# is there any special case for following php code?

Tags: php

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) {

        $data = $_REQUEST['data'];

        $data = json_decode($data);

        if ($data->mail == '(null)') {
            $data->mail = '';
        }

        if ($data->identity == '(null)') {
            $data->identity = '';
        }

}
```

I understand above code like following.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) {

        $data = $_REQUEST['data'];

        $data = json_decode($data);


        if ($data->mail == '') {
            $data->mail = '';
        }

        if ($data->identity == '') {
            $data->identity = '';
        }

}
```

Why did he take '(null)' instead of  '' in the mail,identity variables checking? this is my existing code. I think '(null)' is a some string. why does he comparing this with '(null)' string. Is it for avoiding '(null)' names?

Comment: In the first code you compare that `$data->mail` is exactly the string of `(null)`. It has nothing to do with `null`, as that is a string. Also, the latter examples makes no sense, checking if its empty, then setting it to empty, that does nothing. It's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

May be the values for null properties must be sent as string '(null)' in $_REQUEST['data'], so the original code must be written like that. If you are able to set null values as empty strings or null then probably the below code may work well

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) {

        $data = $_REQUEST['data'];

        $data = json_decode($data);
        if($data){ // Error handling if json_decode gives null for invalid json encoded string
            if (!$data->mail) {
                $data->mail = '';
            }
            if (!$data->identity) {
                $data->identity = '';
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This checks if the value is equal to the string `(null)`.

```
$data->mail == '(null)'
```

This checks if the value is empty

```
$data->mail == ''
```

They aren't equivalent.